# How to draw a line between two points objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

When trying to draw a line between two points (imageViews), the line is generated in another position.

[image]

This is my Code:

```
- (void)drawLine:(UIView*)currentPoint endPoint:(UIImageView*)lastPoint{

    UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:currentPoint.center];
    [path addLineToPoint:lastPoint.center];


    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
    [self.DrawView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

}
```

Comment: everything looks good. can you please share/check the value of CGPoints you are passing to the draw line function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure your `currentPoint` and `lastPoint` is in `self.DrawView`.

Instead of you can add line in `currentPoint.superview.layer` as below

```
- (void)drawLine: (UIView*)currentPoint endPoint:(UIImageView*)lastPoint{
    UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:currentPoint.center];
    [path addLineToPoint:lastPoint.center];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
    [currentPoint.superview.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to give a frame for your CAShapeLayer.

shapeLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)

something like this